# Youtube thumb image (WEBP) doesn't work on firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, youtube, webp

Simply this is my video image that im trying to assign as background to some div , a link can be found here :

https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/9dUCBs3L0Oo/maxresdefault.webp

the image loads in chrome but on firefox , guess it may be some encoding issue , anyone knows why ?

**Edit :**

after searching i found that webp is not supported in firefox :
http://caniuse.com/#feat=webp

However is there any solution i can embed my video image on youtube on firefox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone is searching for answer for same question , Youtube actually avails more than one thumb image to be used the hd version is : `"maxresdefault.jpg"` , so for an example a link provided in question will be :

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9dUCBs3L0Oo/maxresdefault.jpg